# Receiving bad request response when trying to register using ion method

Tags: decentralized-identity

I tried to follow the steps that are defined in the link "https://didproject.azurewebsites.net/docs/registration.html" as is with out any changes to create a sample and complete DID registration to understand the process.

I downloaded the sample and generated necessary public/private keys and completed till the step to generate the payload using the command node makejws which is successful.

After this when i am trying to use the curl command "curl" by replacing the entire text after -- data with the response of payload from the command node makejws . I am receiving an error as Bad request and not sure what is wrong in the command

Curl command that i used is as below

curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{'header':{'alg':'ES256K','kid':'#key-1','operation':'create','proofOfWork':'{}'},'payload':'eyJAY29udGV4dCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vdzNpZC5vcmcvZGlkL3YxIiwicHVibGljS2V5IjpbeyJpZCI6IiNrZXktMSIsInR5cGUiOiJTZWNwMjU2azFWZXJpZmljYXRpb25LZXkyMDE4IiwicHVibGljS2V5SndrIjp7Imt0eSI6IkVDIiwia2lkIjoiI2tleS0xIiwiY3J2IjoiUC0yNTZLIiwieCI6IjVvTEg2ZUVfdWZjZ2VlZ1U2NFo1ZFlEdUxjWWJSV3hsYk1xdFVnbmVRRWMiLCJ5IjoieXZEcXhwaXlCYlZsUlF1cXhHUm54U3hNbDJwSFFTem5Ub0U1dTZKMzBkSSIsInVzZSI6InZlcmlmeSIsImRlZmF1bHRFbmNyeXB0aW9uQWxnb3JpdGhtIjoibm9uZSIsImRlZmF1bHRTaWduQWxnb3JpdGhtIjoiRVMyNTZLIn19XSwic2VydmljZSI6W3siaWQiOiJJZGVudGl0eUh1YiIsInR5cGUiOiJJZGVudGl0eUh1YiIsInNlcnZpY2VFbmRwb2ludCI6eyJAY29udGV4dCI6InNjaGVtYS5pZGVudGl0eS5mb3VuZGF0aW9uL2h1YiIsIkB0eXBlIjoiVXNlclNlcnZpY2VFbmRwb2ludCIsImluc3RhbmNlIjpbImRpZDp0ZXN0Omh1Yi5pZCJdfX1dfQ','signature':'MEYCIQCb7qxCFyIcYumN-HbYqleTc5YldwRnNrhDzlB1DEubQQIhAMkAdsa-BxwV5EghhLljbr84MjkmUYI5narCTnapBcxs'}" -X POST https://beta.ion.microsoft.com/api/1.0/register

Excepted below response

```
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 395
Content-Type: application/json"
```

But receiving

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
request-id: "test"
content-type: text/plain; charset=
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow!  it sounds to me like the problem is with the `curl` command you are issuing;  please post the details (e.g., the full `curl` command), and any pertinent related details (e.g., if you are POST'ing data from a file, please include a minimal example of that file); those details will help people narrow down the problem and suggest solutions and/or other things you should try

Comment: I am using the curl command to post data and posted the command that i am trying to use in the original post. please check if you can find an issue with the command

Comment: I see the problem: I've entered and answer with the solution

Comment: just checking in : did my answer make sense?  would you like anything clarified?  did my answer solve your problem?  as I noted in my answer, changing the quoting resulted in a `200` response for me; do you receive the same result (after applying my change)?

Comment: Not sure what is wrong , it still gives me the same response as bad request. I think as long we are using JSON with in single quote and the parameters & its value in double quotes or vice versa, it doesn't matter as always JSON parses the string properly ,but as you suggested i did try but didn't work

Comment: the quoting absolutely matters; JSON requires "double quotes" -- it's in the spec that way; [RFC 8259](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259); I've updated my answer with the full command and the output showing the `HTTP 200` response

Comment: I've issued the same command a half-dozen times now, and every time it responds with a successful `HTTP 200`; please copy-n-paste the full command from my answer update; if you are still seeing an error, then the problem lies elsewhere, such a mis-behaving proxy or something else interfering; the command with the proper quoting works every time for me

Comment: As you said there is an issue with the communication protocol blocked in my network.It did work in different network where the communication is not blocked. Thanks for the help

Comment: @AparnaTata I am facing the exact same problem. How to check if the communication protocal is blocked and how to enable that? I am using my personal mac with my personal wifi to run this curl command, so am not sure what is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curl command you are using is not sending JSON.  JSON requires "double quotes" around keys and values.

Change all of your ' to ", and wrap it in ' like so:

```
--data '{"header":{"alg":"ES256K",...}' -X POST https://beta.ion.microsoft.com/api/1.0/register
```

When I did that, I received a `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

(Also, the `-X POST` is not necessary - `POST` is already implied by other parts of the `curl` command.)

**UPDATE 1**  Based on your 6/30 comment, I have updated this answer with an unabbreviated form of what I mean, with the curl output showing that it works:

**full curl command**

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"header":{"alg":"ES256K","kid":"#key-1","operation":"create","proofOfWork":"{}"},"payload":"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","signature":"MEYCIQCb7qxCFyIcYumN-HbYqleTc5YldwRnNrhDzlB1DEubQQIhAMkAdsa-BxwV5EghhLljbr84MjkmUYI5narCTnapBcxs"}' -X POST https://beta.ion.microsoft.com/api/1.0/register
```

**curl transmission**

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 52.183.24.15...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to beta.ion.microsoft.com (52.183.24.15) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=beta.ion.microsoft.com
*  start date: Apr 25 21:41:42 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 25 21:41:42 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "beta.ion.microsoft.com" matched cert's "beta.ion.microsoft.com"
*  issuer: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation; OU=Microsoft IT; CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7f9e0e00c600)
> POST /api/1.0/register HTTP/2
> Host: beta.ion.microsoft.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 908
>
```

**curl response**

```
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< request-id: 3545fb10-998e-4871-a28c-bc92e7d82648
< vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
< x-dns-prefetch-control: off
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< x-download-options: noopen
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 828
< server-timing: total;dur=171.0000
< date: Mon, 01 Jul 2019 03:56:45 GMT
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 173
< server: envoy
< 
{
  "@context": "https://w3id.org/did/v1",
  "publicKey": [
    {
      "id": "#key-1",
      "type": "Secp256k1VerificationKey2018",
      "publicKeyJwk": {
        "kty": "EC",
        "kid": "#key-1",
        "crv": "P-256K",
        "x": "5oLH6eE_ufcgeegU64Z5dYDuLcYbRWxlbMqtUgneQEc",
        "y": "yvDqxpiyBbVlRQuqxGRnxSxMl2pHQSznToE5u6J30dI",
        "use": "verify",
        "defaultEncryptionAlgorithm": "none",
        "defaultSignAlgorithm": "ES256K"
      }
    }
  ],
  "service": [
    {
      "id": "IdentityHub",
      "type": "IdentityHub",
      "serviceEndpoint": {
        "@context": "schema.identity.foundation/hub",
        "@type": "UserServiceEndpoint",
        "instance": [
          "did:test:hub.id"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "id": "did:ion:test:EiBXX4kWVIMsvP-evbWvr37Vy2UY32ALpNu9nssBhj_Pdg"
* Connection #0 to host beta.ion.microsoft.com left intact
```